# Perl : handshake mechanism amongs perl scripts

Tags: perl, handshake

I am calling one perl script from another using system() , i want these scripts to have a communication ( handshake kind of mechanism ) where in based on the output of one script i can do further processing in another.

please have a look at this :

lets say i am in main.pl

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl 
  2 
  3 use strict;
  4 use warnings;
  5 use Net::OpenSSH;
  6 
  7 #check for if the socket is established
  8 #call the client (host) script
  9 my $pwd = $ENV{'PWD'};
  10 my $rc = system("$pwd/utpsm_run_automation/utpsm_lts_client.pl")                                 
  11         or die "cant run client.pl $! \n";
```

in the above script that i am calling, i want to see if the connection to server is established, so some handshake mechanism i need , basically for further processing in main.pl, i need to know what was the status of the above script after it runs. am i clear now?

here is client.pl

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/perl
 2 use strict;
 3 use warnings;
 4 use IO::Socket::INET;
 5 use Net::OpenSSH;
 6 #auto-flush on socket
 7 $| = 1;
 8 
 9 #create a connecting socket
 10 my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
 11           PeerHost => 'ltsbm.aus.XX.XX',
 12           PeerPort => 7777,
 13           Proto => 'tcp',
 14           );
 15 die "cannot connect to the server$! \n" unless     $socket;                                          
 16 print "VIRU ::connected to the server \n";
 17 
 18 #data to send to the server
 19 my $req = 'VIRU :: Sending data \n';
 20 sleep(20);
 21 my $size = $socket->send($req);
 22 
 23 #sending file over socket using scp
```

This is client.pl

Comment: Your question is vague.  Could you provide a more concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you just want to know if the system command failed, or do you want the output?

Comment: You can use the `( system($cmd) == 0 ) or die "Unable to run '$cmd' : $!";` construct

Comment: To just capture the output, `my ($output) = qx( $cmd );`

Comment: @Arjit : added the client.pl fyi

Comment: The idea of calling a new program is not good. you can write your own function for your program and return your desired data to your **main.pl**. now you can tell us what kind of return statement you want by your **client.pl** script

Comment: This is a big automation script, so i can't put functions like you said, this is decided architecture so we have to follow that, i was thinking instead of capturing output why not put in a log file and everytime read from there , what is your suggestion on this ?

Comment: Still I would suggest you to use function. you can split your big script and write different functions . The reason for the suggestion is you can easily monitor any part of big script via function and in future it will help you and function feature is there in perl for this kind of complex cases.

Comment: A solution, perhaps cleanest for this, is to set up a [`pipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html) between the main and the client, but for which the main should start the client via `fork`+`exec` instead of `system`. See my answer to your previous question, for links as well. Another way would be for the client to drop a file to the disk, which the main would check, but that is borne with timing issues, and clumsy. Yet another, for the client to send a SIGUSR1 (or 2) to main, for which it needs to know main's PID (via `getppid` If the shell does not get involved).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous commenters that the general idea isn't very good in the first place. Whoever came up with that architecture requirement probably knows a bit of shell scripting but not Perl.

That said, if you're sure your output isn't very long and it's fine to process it only when the child process has completed, @xxfelixxx's idea of using `qx//` is definitely the easiest. If you'd like to process output while the child is still running and/or the output may be so large that it's better to process it line by line, you can easily set up a pipe in an `open()` call:

`open my $pipe, '-|', $program_name or die "Could not run $program_name: $!';
while(<$pipe>) {
  ... # read process output
}`

Much easier and less error prone than setting up a named pipe and doing a `fork()/exec()` dance yourself for simple tasks like this.

Comment: (1) If you state that "_the general idea isn't very good_" it would be good to explain why you think so. The "_previous commenters_" didn't either.  (2) By your comment of `qx` it follows that you offer the `open` as a solution for when the child is long running. But if the parent exits first this "_easier and less error prone_" code you show will crash the child on its first next print to STDOUT, via SIGPIPE, and without a word. Yes, `open` is cleaner, but that also hides the complexities -- it does not remove them. Please complete your solution, this is dangerously misleading.

Comment: Btw, the OP seems to be asking for a mere "_handshake_", and then each go on their own. Your answer doesn't provide for that.

Comment: @zdim, Running external scripts for trivial things that could just as well live in a module is unnecessarily limiting regarding non-scalar data, error prone (think quoting) and slow. The parent in my example _can't_ exit first because the loop doesn't terminate until the child has closed its standard output, typically by exiting. Of course you can break out of the loop and kill the child anyway, but manual forking doesn't remedy that in any way either.

Comment: How is a client, whose job we don't know, a "_trivial thing_"? Further, you just stated it all -- it is the parent "_in your example_" that can't exit, and the child _in your example_ is robbed of its STDOUT.. While the Q isn't crystal clear, it does indicate that the parent only needs to know that the child connected to its server. Then it goes on with its own job. There is every reason for a child to be able to close (an explicit) pipe, so the two can go on and do their things.  This seems to need more control over the comms (pipe) than what the "_easier_" `open` allows.

Comment: Btw, why are you mentioning a "_named pipe_"? Nobody invoked that.

Comment: What I mean to say is -- if the parent merely needs to know that the child connected (which the Q does state), with the `open` that you recommend it can read the pipe once and go on.  Then, if it happens to exit first (what we don't know), the child had better be careful to never again go to its STDOUT (unless it handles SIGPIPE).  While we don't know whether the child may need its STDOUT for other purposes.  None of that is good..

Comment: Sorry, @zdim, the "named pipe" thing was a misreading on my part. However, as the OP "need[s] to know what was the status of the above script after it runs" I don't see how to "go on and do their things" is an issue here. "sending file over socket using scp" does sound pretty trivial to me.

Comment: I completely agree that the question is very unclear. I'd still say that due to "_see if the connection to server_", and "_handshake_" one should allow the scripts to exchange information and be able to proceed. The problem, of course, is that OP also uses "_output_" and "_status ... after_".  However, if it's that simple then just a `qx` does it all. But if there is anything more they'll need more control.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a list of possible outcomes of client.pl.
Create a return code table for your reference for each possible outcome of the client script, for example:

```
0 = success connecting to server
1 = unable to ping remote server
2 = socket error
```

At the point before the client script finishes have it exit with a return code. Example:

```
exit 1;
```

Now have the main script catch the return code & parse it through an if statement. The main script can take action based on what return code was returned form the client script.